# Euler totient function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var phi=function(n){var count=" "  //an empty string
for(var i =1;i<=n;i++){
if(for(var j=1;j<=i;j++){
i%j===0;n%j===0;count += j.str;})   //appended the j as string into count
{return count.length;}}
};
```

The Euler totient function `phi(n)` gives the number of numbers <= `n` which are relatively prime to `n`.

Comment: Whitespace. Whitespace is good.

Comment: What programming challenge is this?

Comment: My JS interpreters are telling me this isn't syntactically valid - which is as it should be. A `for` in an `if`??

Comment: I was just trying to implement the Euler totient function.It was nothing to do with any particular programming challenge.I was trying to understand algorithms & implement them on my own.Well,if you people can suggest me anything on this would be very helpful.

Comment: This looks like code for PPCG ._.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first off, *whitespace*:

```
var phi=function(n){var count=" "  //an empty string
for(var i =1;i<=n;i++){
if(for(var j=1;j<=i;j++){
i%j===0;n%j===0;count += j.str;})   //appended the j as string into count
{return count.length;}}
};
```

has far to little. I reformatted and made this (put in a couple of semicolons, too):

```
var phi = function (n) {
    var count = " ";  //an empty string
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            i % j === 0;
            n % j === 0;
            count += j.str; //appended the j as string into count
        }) {
            return count.length;
        }
    }
};
```

`" "` is *not* an empty string. `""` is.

Now, why the *heck* do you have a `for` in an `if`? Try rewriting it without one. [`Array#all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) ought to help you with that. Once I get a chance I'll try my hand at it.

`.str` isn't needed. Just write `count += j`.

I can't comment on your algorithm because I can't tell what it is. *This is why we write readable code*. Don't use stupid hacks that make your program .03% faster that make you use stupid, unreadable tricks like, say, *putting a `for` in an `if`*. Prioritize readability until you absolutely have to do otherwise.